# Assume $G$ is a group and $H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$,moreover for every $x,y \in G\setminus H$: $xy \in H$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Assume $G$ is a group and $H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$,moreover for every $x,y \in G\setminus H$: $xy \in H$,then:

- $H$ is an Abelian group
- $G/H$ is cyclic
- $G/H$ is Abelian
- $G/H$ is finite

---

By the definition of normal subgroup $yx=y(xy)y^{-1} \in H$ but I think since this $x,y$ are not in $H$,so $H$ is not necessarily an Abelian group, I think if we show that $H$ is Abelian then we also able to show that $G/H$ is cyclic, but I don't know how to show that $H$ is Abelian.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If $G = S_n$ (symmetric group on $n$ letters) and $H = A_n$ (alternating subgroup) for $n \ge 4$, then your assumptions hold, but $H$ is not abelian.

Comment: Hint: Translate the statement to one about elements in the quotient.

Answer (score 2):

We have two possibilities: $H=G$, in wich case we have nothing to do and $H$ is not necessarily abelian, and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Suppose $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Let $x\in G\setminus H$. For all $y\in G\setminus H$ we have that $xy\in H$ and so $yH=(xH)^{-1}$. Analogously, we have that $yH=(yH)^{-1}$. It follows that $(xH)^{-1}=(yH)^{-1}$ and so $xH=yH$. It means that $G/H=\{H,xH\}$ is a group cyclic of order $2$. Finally, $H$ need no being abelian as in the comment of Rob Arthan.

Comment: And we don't even need to assume that the subgroup is normal since that also follows from the other condition.

Comment: I didn't realize it, very good.

Comment: @45465: If $H=G$, then the property that for every $x,y\in G-H$ something happens is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). There is no contradiction.

Comment: @46465: $G/H$ is a group. If $(yH)(xH)=H$, then $yH$ is the inverse  of $xH$.

Comment: @45465: I *just* told you how. $(xH)(yH) = xyH = H$ (because $xy\in H$). So $yH$ is the multiplicative inverse of $xH$ in $G/H$. Do you know what quotient groups are? If you do not, then you have bigger issues than this problem, and you are most definitely not in a position to attempt it. Instead, you need to go back and learn the basics.

Comment: @46465: It seems to me that you are not familiar with the notions of quotient groups. Therefore, you should consult an introductory book on group theory.